# K&R C - Adding '\0' after a newline

Tags: c, string

I am working with the 2nd edition of The C Programming Language by K & R.

In the example program on pg. 29, the authors create a function called `getline()`, whose purpose is to count the number of chars in a line and also append a `'\0'` to the end of a line (after the newline character `'\n'`).

My question is, why do you want to do that? Can't you figure out the start of a newline by the fact that you have the newline character?

Comment: Have you ever worked with C strings?

Answer (score 3):

I think the intent is to *split the text into lines*.

In the C data model, `\0` marks the end of the string. You can be given a string with multiple lines signaled by `\n`, but it'll have a single `\0`, at the end.

If you put a `\0` after every `\n`, you are effectively splitting the string into lines, one `\0`-terminated string for each line.

Comment: Thank you! Great answer. All the comments below were very helpful as well.

Answer (score 1):

In C, there's no string type properly speaking (like in Java or C# for example). For C it's just a sequence of bytes until a 0 byte is found. This is called a NUL-terminated (do not confuse with `NULL` constant) or zero-terminated string.

So `\0` is appended to make it a valid C string that represents a line and be able to manipulate it as a normal C string afterwards (e.g. use `strlen` function). If you don't append a `\0` the character count will be wrong because you don't know where the string ends. To show this, here's an example:

If take a look at a C string containing "Hello" in memory, we find this:

```
48 65 6C 6C 
6F 00 A4 00
```

48 65 6C 6C 6F is "Hello", plus a 00 byte (\0) that terminates it. So to count how many characters, we just count bytes until a 00 byte that terminates it, that is 5 bytes (5 characters).

If you don't zero-terminate the string, then there's no way to know how many characters the string has. This is what the memory would look like for a non-zero-terminated "Hello" string:

```
48 65 6C 6C 
6F A4 00 FF
```

As you can see, there's no way to know where the string ends, and hence, impossible to count how many bytes it has.

Answer (score 1):

The presence of the `\0` character has nothing to do with the [newline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline) (which is not always `\n` in binary streams - see comment by Keith Thompson).

Newline is used for the on-screen formatting, (and is denoted in binary by a line feed, a carriage return, or both, depending on the platform); while `\0` is used to mark the end of a string, which is, in C, a mere array of characters, with no inherent end.

Comment: In C, the newline *is* always represented as `'\n'`. For text streams, the system's end-of-line representation is converted to `'\n'` on input and vice versa on output. (The conversion happens to be trivial for Unix-like systems.)

Comment: You are right, I will edit my answer accordingly. (and voted +1)

Answer (score 0):

I agree to the answers above, '\0' just marks the end of the string, it is important in some
functions such as strcmp. If there is no '\0' in a char array, the program may sometimes return random characters after the string.